# Quickly resize all artboards and objects on artboards to tablet size in Adobe XD

Tags: resize, artboard, adobe-xd

I have a project that has mobile designs which are for phones.

I'm wondering if it's possible to quickly and programmatically resize all artboards and objects on the artboards to tablet size?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe XD doesn't have a "re-layout" resize feature yet, but please upvote these requests to indicate your interest:

- [Responsive artboards / adaptive layout constraints for resizing](https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007/suggestions/12942171-responsive-artboards-adaptive-layout-constraints)
- [Resizable symbols](https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007/suggestions/16939339-scale-resize-symbols-individually)